# What is this fungus in my plant growth medium?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I am growing *S. lycopersicum* on 1x [Gamborgs medium](https://www.duchefa-biochemie.com/product/details/number/G0209) and have been getting some fungal like contamination. The media contains 0.2% sucrose and Bacto-Agar. Plants are grown at a 21 c - 20 c day, night cycle. The contamination is characterised by squiggly string like structures that penetrate the agar. Structures vary in size but are usually 1-3 millimetres.

[image]

EDIT:

Under Compound microscope:

100x

[image: 100x]

200x

[image: 200x]

400x

[image: 400x]

Comment: any chance you could pick a few out and get pictures on a slide under a compound microscope?

Comment: And an overall photo of the fungal colonies if you can get them. Also: [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000715363780008X) might be some use. They list several genera with spiral hyphae.

Comment: I will upload the compound now, it's not very clear as the structures are buried in the agar.

Comment: I have tried putting it under a slide but the stucture does not stay intact

Comment: Interesting - I don't see any cellular structures, but, as you say, this might be because of integrity and clarity issues. Could it be the track of something like a nematode or a protozoan, as it looks like a burrow?

Comment: Burrow like a leaf miner caterpillar might make inside a leaf that is. Though the regularity of the shape makes a biological structure more likely. Could you get a sample from each end and see what's there? An inverted microscope might be able to give you some depth if you are looking through the agar, but optical clarity will be a problem with the agar. Another thing to check would be to see if you can get it to replicate - take a sample onto a fresh plate (no plant) and see if it multiplies/grows.